# global variable but still can't access in linux

Tags: linux, unix, shell, ant

i have trying to use some global variable in my ant file.
when i do login through terminal. i can access those variable like `JAVA_HOME`
but when i am trying to access variable through the ant command i am not able to find them.
global variable declared in .cshrc

```
setenv JAVA_HOME jdk_full_path
```

ant code using variable.

```
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ear" value= "true"/>
<property name="home" value="${env.HOME}"/>
<property name="java_home" value="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
```

i can access home variable but i am not able to find `JAVA_HOME` variable ,i am executing this ant through eclipse

Please suggest me where should i declare the variable so i can access them

Comment: The term "global" is not defined and is probably contributing to your confusion. You're talking about an environment variable set in your shell login script. There is *no* concept of "global" for environment variables: every process has it's own environment (which it usually but not always inherits from its parent process) and then can change to its heart's content without effecting *any other* process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that Eclipse doesn't have `JAVA_HOME` in its environment.

Try logging out and back in again, then run Eclipse.

Alternatively, open a terminal, and run Eclipse from there.

Comment: wow i never thought in that way,it works. starting it from terminal 
is there any permanent solution to this problem so when i directly start eclipse those variable also get loaded .

Comment: If you've added them to the `.cshrc` file they will be added to the environment of your desktop session when you log in. Then if you run Eclipse (either using a launcher, or by opening a terminal and running it from there) the variable will be propagated down to Eclipse. Until you log out and in again, you will have to open a terminal, which will get the new variable, and run Eclipse from there.

Answer (score 0):

The .cshrc file is only run when you start a new C shell, it is not for global variables. Since you are not starting Eclipse from the C shell it will not see any variables you set there.

Try the ~/.login file or the /etc/profile file in case eclipse starts up using bash. Both of these files are only loaded once when the user logs on so they should effect everything. You may require a restart or even a reboot for changes to these files to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are inherited through process execution, they are not global. So, when you edit your shell's RC file to add a variable, it only takes effect for shells executed AFTER that modification, and for programs executed from those shells. If you started Eclipse from KDE/Gnome, and KDE/Gnome was started before you made that change, then KDE/Gnome never had the definition and therefore Eclipse did not either.

I recommend logging out and back in. Also, depending on your default shell setting, you may find that KDE/Gnome is being started through bash or something else, meaning that you'll need to modify .bashrc instead of .cshrc.

Answer (score 0):

You should define this variables at one of the following files:

~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile runs only with login shells i.e when you first log in into system.

~/.bashrc file runs every time you open a new non-login bash shell such as xterm

So, you should add to this files the line:

> export JAVA_HOME=jdk_full_path

You must re-login for the changes take efect